# Use laptop as a remote display for linux

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, fedora

since I don't have enough space for a Monitor, I want to use my laptop as a screen for my Desktop PC which is running linux fedora. My laptop is running on windows 7 and I don't want to change that or disassemble the screen.

perhaps that is possible via a local Network?

If I was using win 7 on Desktop PC, I know I could use [Air Display](http://avatron.com/apps/air-display), but what about on a linux?

Comment: I noticed you got a downvote. You might try changing the title of your question to get better answers. I'd suggest clarifying if you're trying to do a headless install or use software like Remote Desktop Client in the title.

Comment: Thank you. I Edited the title and context, I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this link may help you:
http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/User_Guide/chap-User_Guide-Sharing_your_desktop.html

or remote desktop connection to Fedora.

Comment: Add description on how the link helps

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a monitor for the Desktop PC at all, you want to do a headless install. Once installed you can use RDP or SSH to show the OS from the desktop on your laptop.

## Reference

### Headless install

- [Headless linux install](https://serverfault.com/questions/21255/headless-linux-install)
- [How can I install Ubuntu on a headless machine?`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13106/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-on-a-headless-machine)

### RDP/SSH

- [RDP into your Linux Desktop](http://www.linux.org/threads/rdp-into-your-linux-desktop.8/)
- [RDP vs. SSH/SSL/VPN for Security](http://www.eberlysystems.com/blog/2009/12/rdp-vs-sshsslvpn-security-and-usability/)